# Unable to throw expection in feign builder

Tags: java, ioexception, feign

Im trying to add variable in my feign.builder but it keep saying that

> Unhandled exceptions: java.net.URISyntaxException, java.io.IOException

throwing exceptions doesn't work neither catching any ideas how to fix this?
Feign Builder:

```
 Interface.DeleteComment deleteComment = Feign.builder()
                                              .client(new OkHttpClient())
                                              .encoder(new JacksonEncoder())
                                              .decoder(new JacksonDecoder())
                                              .logger(new Slf4jLogger(Interface.DeleteComment.class))
                                              .logLevel(Logger.Level.FULL)
                                              .target(Interface.DeleteComment.class, 
                                                      "http://localhost:3000/comments/" + networkConfigurationProperties.id());
```

NetworkConfigurationProperties

```
public class NetworkConfigurationProperties  {
    public String id() throws URISyntaxException,IOException {
        final URI uri = new URI("http://localhost:3000/comments/");
        String path = uri.getPath();
        String idStr = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        return idStr;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `id()` method can throw those Exceptions, meaning, they have to be handled (somewhere).

In your calling method, you can't just say:

```
public void callId() {
Interface.DeleteComment deleteComment = Feign.builder()
                    .client(new OkHttpClient())
                    .encoder(new JacksonEncoder())
                    .decoder(new JacksonDecoder())
                    .logger(new Slf4jLogger(Interface.DeleteComment.class))
                    .logLevel(Logger.Level.FULL)
                    .target(Interface.DeleteComment.class, "http://localhost:3000/comments/" + networkConfigurationProperties.id());
}
```

because you don't handle the Exceptions. You'll need to either catch them:

```
public void callId() {
  try{
    Interface.DeleteComment deleteComment = Feign.builder()
                        .client(new OkHttpClient())
                        .encoder(new JacksonEncoder())
                        .decoder(new JacksonDecoder())
                        .logger(new Slf4jLogger(Interface.DeleteComment.class))
                        .logLevel(Logger.Level.FULL)
                        .target(Interface.DeleteComment.class, "http://localhost:3000/comments/" + networkConfigurationProperties.id());
    } catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace(); //or similar
   }
    }
```

or let the method(s) calling that method know to expect possible Exceptions, by propagating them

```
public void callId() throws URISyntaxException,IOException {
Interface.DeleteComment deleteComment = Feign.builder()
                    .client(new OkHttpClient())
                    .encoder(new JacksonEncoder())
                    .decoder(new JacksonDecoder())
                    .logger(new Slf4jLogger(Interface.DeleteComment.class))
                    .logLevel(Logger.Level.FULL)
                    .target(Interface.DeleteComment.class, "http://localhost:3000/comments/" + networkConfigurationProperties.id());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a try catch block in your id() method. Your id() method throws two checked exception, which must be catched. Try something like this:

```
public class NetworkConfigurationProperties  {
    public String id() {
         try {
            final URI uri = new URI("http://localhost:3000/comments/");
            String path = uri.getPath();
            String idStr = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
            return idStr;
         } catch (URISyntaxException|IOException e) {
            return null;
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: if you look at the calling code, you might spot the flaw in that approach

Comment: my networkConfigurationProperties.id() is always empty any idea how to fix that?